# how to handle a lot of buttons and fields

Tags: swift

I've a another newbee question...

I have a viewcontroller with 30 buttons (called day1...day30) and 30 textfields (called field1...field30). For each combination of a button and a textfield I have some code, like this:

```
@IBAction func day1(sender: UIButton) {
if day1.backgroundColor != UIColor.greenColor() {
        day1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        field1.enabled = false
    } else {
        day1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        field1.enabled = true
    }
}
```

My questions... (1) can this be done in a better/shorter way and (2) do I have to write this code for all 30 buttons / field combinations, or is there a smarter way?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it programmatically:

First you create a loop where you make your 30 buttons. As you see, I set the `tag` property of each button and use the index so that we can check which button is pressed later and react on it properly. The size and position of the buttons will be set through the index(`index*30`):

```
for index in 0...30{
    //Set Position of the button by using the index
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(index)*30, 50, 50))

    //Set the tag so you can check it later
    button.tag = index
    button.currentTitle = "Button \(index)"

    //Sets, which method should be called when the button is pressed
    button.addTarget(button, action: Selector("aButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}
```

Then, we create a method which we called in the for-loop and check which tag the pressed button had:

```
//Sender is the button which is pressed
func aButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    switch sender.tag{
    case 1:
        println("first pressed")
    case 2:
        println("second pressed")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. That's new for me... I was just getting used to IB. Can I mix the approach? Do the buttons and fields as you proposed, and the other interface elements with IB?

Comment: Yes you can. You can give your IBOutlets also tags and targets. So you could mix it like that.

Comment: I'll give it a try Christian. Thanks again.

Comment: I have to put that in ViewDidLoad? Then I get an error from the compiler stating 'Cannot assign to currentTitle in button'.